# How can i use a custom font in word press

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So i relized the company im  building a website for the website looks a little bland. I want to know if i can import a file of custom characters into word press. so far it hasnt loaded, if anyone knows a better solution let me know please

I tried to upload the file

Comment: have you looked into using [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com)? that's usually the easiest option

Comment: Using a cdn to deliver the fonts (like google fonts) is much faster too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can start by converting your custom font file (usually in formats like `.ttf` or `.woff`) into web-compatible formats using online converters.

Once converted, you can upload the font files to your WordPress theme directory, typically under the `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name` folder. Then, in your theme's CSS file (`style.css`), you can define the font using the `@font-face` rule and associate it with specific elements on your website.

Remember to specify the font-family in your CSS to apply it to desired elements, and you should see your custom font beautifully integrated into your WordPress site.

Happy designing!